# Quickly load part of image in java

Tags: java, image, memory, tile

I'm currently working in a map editor for a 2D, tile based game. When I create a new map, the tileset is loaded into memory and displayed in a JPanel that's inside a JScrollPane, so I can choose the tiles I wish to draw.

At first, I was just drawing the full image, but that made scrolling pretty slow, so now I only draw the visible portion of it and that works just fine. What I'm worried about is the memory usage, because the tileset is pretty big. I'm not getting any OutOfMemory erros, but I would like to optimise everything I can.

I tried using ImageReader together with ImageReadParam.setSourceRegion(); and that uses a lot less memory, but the scrolling becomes slower and the image blinks like crazy when scrolling - probably because it takes some time to read the image form disk.

So, is there a good way to quickly load parts of a big image without fully loading it? Or maybe there's a way to fully load it but in a compressed manner?

Comment: If you have a tileset, why not draw individual tiles?  You should probably have one 'reference' tile, and then a grid of references to that tile.  I'd see about only loading tiles at full quality on demand, if it's really necessary - what does your profiling tell you?

Comment: The only time I've ever had an issue with an image was when I was trying to load and render 16K by 16K textures. Can we see some code for how you are loading and rendering the image?

Comment: I'm not having problems with memory, it's just that I feel like there should be a better way to show the image than fully loading it into memory, since I'm not displaying all of it at once.